# Can javascript be enabled only when the user is on a mobile devices?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out how to make a javascript line work only when the user is using a mobile device.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Take this (probably outdated) **regular expression from hell** to check for mobile phones:

```
function isMobileBrowser() {
  var a = navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera;

  return (/android|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a) || 
      /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)));
}
```

I give full credit to this incredible page here:

http://detectmobilebrowser.com/

Answer (score 1):

Use `navigator.userAgent` to get the userAgent of the user and then change your code accordingly.

I'd create an array from mobile userAgents and then check if the current userAgent is in the array, see this list to get you started:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_user_agents_for_mobile_phones

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm quite new with javascript!

This is the code I need to work only with mobile devices:

function installSpecialEffects() {
function changeNavPosition() {   
  $('#logo').css('top', window.innerHeight + window.scrollY - 500 + "px");
} 

$(document).bind('scroll', function() {
  changeNavPosition();
});

}
installSpecialEffects();

And this is to find out if the device is an iPhone:

var deviceIphone = "iphone";

function DetectIphone()
{
   if (uagent.search(deviceIphone) > -1)
      return true;
   else
      return false;

How do I put them together??
Thanks for your time!

Comment: Oh, and that's my fault? Thanks a lot ... http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=user+agents+for+mobile+phones

Comment: I first thought that that list was already disputed at the time you posted it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Articles_for_deletion/List_of_user_agents_for_mobile_phones and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Articles_for_deletion/List_of_user_agent_strings... but that might have been a bit quick on my side. Sorry for that...

Answer (score 1):

you could check if the client is using a mobile device (i.e. [here](http://www.hand-interactive.com/resources/detect-mobile-javascript.htm)) and then:

```
if(isMobile){
    //executeMyJsCode
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check the user agent before running the script. If it contains a keyword, or is found in an array of agents, you run your script - else, you jump ship.

Answer (score 0):

You can use enquire.js. Its for media queries for javascript callbacks.

Ref: enquire.js[1](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/)

Answer (score -1):

Inspect the global `navigator.userAgent` to identify different devices.

For example iPhone:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/iPhone/) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: As surprising as it may sound, there are a lot more mobile devices besides the iPhone

Comment: Even this simple naive sample wont work... `.toLowerCase()` will require you to `match(/iphone/)` and not `iPhone`